# Creation of ROS2 subscriptions dynamically in loop vs manually

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I am working with ROS2 in Python. I want to create a single node, subscribed to topics to get the pose of multiple robots. I'd like to be able to adjust to different numbers of robots, and so I'm trying to create subscriptions dynamically, and pass the corresponding topic to each callback so I can determine which topic data has been received from (as in [this question](https://answers.ros.org/question/398554/dynamic-publishers-subscribers-and-callbacks/?answer=398555#post-id-398555)) I've created a node initialized with a list of subscription definitions, with a loop to create subscribers, each referencing the same callback as below:

```
class SubNode(Node):
    def __init__(self,name, subscription_definitions=[('/robot1/pose', Pose), ('/robot2/pose', Pose)]):
        super().__init__(node_name=name)
        for topic_definition in subscription_definitions:
            self.create_subscription(
                topic= topic_definition[0],
                msg_type= topic_definition[1],
                callback= lambda msg: self.listener_callback(msg, topic_definition[0]),
                qos_profile= 10
                )
        
    def listener_callback(self, msg, topic):
        self.get_logger().info(f'SubNode callback heard {msg} on {topic}')
```

However, when this node receives data, the callback only ever reports the topic as the final entry in the subscription definitions (here `/robot2/pose`). However, when I hard-code the creation of these subscriptions, as below:

```
class SubNode(Node):
    def __init__(self,name, subscription_definitions=[('/robot1/pose', Pose), ('/robot2/pose', Pose)]):
        super().__init__(node_name=name)
            
        self.create_subscription(topic_definitions[0][1], topic_definitions[0][0],lambda msg: self.listener_callback(msg, topic_definitions[0][0]),10)
        self.create_subscription(topic_definitions[1][1], topic_definitions[1][0],lambda msg: self.listener_callback(msg, topic_definitions[1][0]),10)
...
```

It works. What's happening when I loop over the list rather than statically initialize them that makes it fail? I assume it's something to do with an overwriting issue, but I'm stumped.

Any advice is appreciated. I was able to fix the issue by using partial() in the subscription creation, as below (which further makes me think that it has to do with Python overwriting the callback, as partial would create a new object), but I'd like to understand why my initial approach failed.

```
self.create_subscription(
                topic= topic_definition[0],
                msg_type= topic_definition[1],
                callback= partial(self.listener_callback, topic=topic_definition[0]),
                qos_profile= 10
                )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not storing your subscriptions.

```
    for topic_definition in subscription_definitions:
        self.my_subs.append(self.create_subscription(
            topic= topic_definition[0],
            msg_type= topic_definition[1],
            callback= lambda msg: self.listener_callback(msg, topic_definition[0]),
            qos_profile= 10
            ))
```

I can't speak why your hardcoding works, that is odd. I'm actually surprised any of it works without storing the instance to keep it in scope.

Comment: Thanks for the info! It working without storing may have to do with how I'm wrapping the node later on... I'll test it in isolation. After some more reading, the hard coding vs looping has to do with creating lambda's in loops and their scope; for anyone else who might end up here, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/938429/scope-of-lambda-functions-and-their-parameters/938493#938493) is what answered my question